# OpenGL vertex attrib pointer or shader not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I have a problem with displaying a model I loaded ussing Assimp. Model is loaded correctly and was displayed earlier but I was using only vertex data without normals etc.

Now when I even delete whole code of shader its drawing me a white model. Can anybody explain that to me?

Here is mesh loading helper method:

```
Model * MeshHelper::loadModelFromObjFile( char * filePath )
{
    Model * model = new Model();

    const aiScene* scene = aiImportFile ( filePath, aiProcess_Triangulate); 

    if (!scene) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: reading mesh %s\n", filePath);
        return false;
    }
    printf ("%i animations\n", scene->mNumAnimations);
    printf ("%i cameras\n", scene->mNumCameras);
    printf ("%i lights\n", scene->mNumLights);
    printf ("%i materials\n", scene->mNumMaterials);
    printf ("%i meshes\n", scene->mNumMeshes);
    printf ("%i textures\n", scene->mNumTextures);

    for (unsigned int m_i = 0; m_i < scene->mNumMeshes; m_i++) {
        const aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[m_i];

        GLuint vertexBuffer, normalBuffer, textureBuffer;

        Mesh * modelMesh = new Mesh();
        modelMesh->vertexCount = mesh->mNumVertices;

        glGenVertexArrays( 1, &modelMesh->vertexArray );
        glBindVertexArray( modelMesh->vertexArray );

        for (unsigned int v_i = 0; v_i < mesh->mNumVertices; v_i++) 
        {
            if (mesh->HasPositions ()) {
                const aiVector3D* vp = &(mesh->mVertices[v_i]);
                glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * mesh->mNumVertices, mesh->mVertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
                glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL );
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            }
            // buffer for vertex normals
            if (mesh->HasNormals()) {
                glGenBuffers(1, &normalBuffer);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * mesh->mNumVertices, mesh->mNormals, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
                glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL );
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
            }

            // buffer for vertex texture coordinates
            if (mesh->HasTextureCoords(0)) {
                float *texCoords = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * 2 * mesh->mNumVertices);
                for (unsigned int k = 0; k < mesh->mNumVertices; ++k) {

                    texCoords[k*2]   = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][k].x;
                    texCoords[k*2+1] = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][k].y; 

                }
                glGenBuffers(1, &textureBuffer);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer);
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 2 * mesh->mNumVertices, texCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                //glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
                //glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);

            }
            if (mesh->HasTangentsAndBitangents ()) {
                // NB: could store/print tangents here
            }

            glBindVertexArray(0);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        }

        model->meshCollection->push_back( modelMesh );
    }
    aiReleaseImport (scene);

    return model;
}
```

Model class contains:

```
std::vector<Mesh*> * meshCollection;
```

Mesh has the VAO index and number of points to draw
Drawing method of Mesh

```
void Mesh::draw()
{
    glBindVertexArray( vertexArray );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount );
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Here is vertex shader and fragment

vertex

```
#version 400

layout( location = 0 ) in vec3 aPosition;
layout( location = 1 ) in vec3 aNormal;

uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;

out vec3 vNormal;

void main()
{
    vNormal = aNormal;
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4 ( aPosition, 1.0);
};
```

fragment

```
#version 400

out vec4 frag_colour;
in vec3 vNormal;

void main()
{
    frag_colour = vec4 ( vNormal, 1.0) * vec4( 0.5 );
};
```

Shader loading

```
GLuint vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource (vs, 1, &vertexShader, NULL );
glCompileShader (vs);
GLuint fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource (fs, 1, &fragmentShader, NULL);
glCompileShader (fs);

program = glCreateProgram();

glAttachShader (program, fs);
glAttachShader (program, vs);
glLinkProgram (program);
```

Comment: you need to keep `glEnableVertexAttribArray` active while calling the `glDraw*` functions

Comment: I removed the glDisableVertexAttribArray(); for vertices and normals and it showed up but still shader seems to not take any effect on the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the normal as the color value. 
The Normal is used to calculate the resulting color of a illumination process.
eg DiffuseLighting. The normal represents an orthogonal directional vector from a given face (triangle). It is used to calculate the angle between a light direction and a surface to
determine the luminance intesity.

What you need is to load the material information from your mesh and pass this
information to the fragment shader.

UPDATE due to comment:

enable the normalBuffer and the texturebuffer also within your draw method.

Here is an extract of render method of mine:
What you can see is that i enable all necessary buffers and also all VertexAttributeArrays
so correct VertexAttributes are passed to the shader program.
This code is executed for each Model (Mesh) i have.

void VEModel::render(VEEnvironment &environment, glm::mat4 &parentModel) {

```
glUseProgram( shaderProgram );

glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, polygonModel);

glm::mat4 proj = environment.getProjection();
VECamera* cam = &environment.getActiveCamera();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo );

GLint refModel    = getUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "model" );
GLint refView     = getUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "view" );
GLint refProj     = getUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "proj" );

glUniformMatrix4fv( refView, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( cam->getCamera() ) );
glUniformMatrix4fv( refProj, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( proj ) );
glUniformMatrix4fv( refModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( modelMatrix ) );

applyLights(environment);


GLint posAttrib = getAttributeLocation(shaderProgram, "vertPosition");
GLint normalAttrib = getAttributeLocation(shaderProgram, "vertNormal");
GLint colAttrib = getAttributeLocation(shaderProgram, "vertColor");

glEnableVertexAttribArray( posAttrib );
glVertexAttribPointer( posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexAttrLen * sizeof(float), (void*) ( 0 * sizeof(float) ) );


glEnableVertexAttribArray( normalAttrib );
glVertexAttribPointer( normalAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexAttrLen * sizeof(float), (void*) ( 3 * sizeof(float) ));


glEnableVertexAttribArray( colAttrib );
glVertexAttribPointer( colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexAttrLen * sizeof(float), (void*) ( 6 * sizeof(float) ) );

int offset = 0;
int texUnitOffset = 0;
//glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, maxIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);


for(std::vector<VEGeometryObject *>::iterator geometry = geometryObjects.begin(); geometry != geometryObjects.end(); ++geometry) {
    if ((*geometry)->hasTexture()) {

        for (int i=0; i<(*geometry)->getTextureCount(); i++) {
            glActiveTexture( i +  texUnitOffset);
            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i+texUnitOffset] );
            //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // i + texUnitOffset);

            (*geometry)->enableTextureStates();
            /*
            fprintf(stderr, "Enabled texture buffer TBO %i\n", textures[i+texUnitOffset]);
            */

            GLint texAttrib = getAttributeLocation( shaderProgram, "vertUV" );
            glEnableVertexAttribArray( texAttrib );
            glVertexAttribPointer( texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexAttrLen * sizeof(float), (void*)( 9 * sizeof(float) ) );

            /*GLint uniTime = getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "time");
            glUniform1f(uniTime, (GLfloat)clock() / (GLfloat)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);*/
            glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "sampler" ), i + texUnitOffset );
        }

        texUnitOffset++;
    }
    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (*geometry)->getVertexCount());
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, maxIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*) offset) ;
    offset += (*geometry)->getFaceCount();
}

glDisableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalAttrib);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
```

}

Here is a really sophosticated tutorial which explains the 
Buffer concepts in a really nice way: http://open.gl/introduction

Comment: I know, but normals should change the model colour anyway. I could remove the whole shader code and the model still shows up and its white ?! :(

Comment: How is that possible ?

Comment: Its reuqired to pass vertex data to buffer and bind buffer to vao every time the model is being drawed ?

Comment: Is the resulting VertexAttributeArray correct. Maybe you assign to less information during the mesh loading process and there is some undefined value within the array you pass to the shader.

Comment: No passing the vertex data is just needed one time. But you have to bind each time before calling any drawMethod all relevant buffers. In your case glBindBuffer for vertexBuffer, NormalBuffer, texturBuffer of each mesh. The OpenGL State machine uses than all enabled buffers for the rendering process.

Comment: Yes data is passed correctly. I checked normals and vertices.

Comment: I cant bind to buffers and buffers to vertex array and just call vertex array ?

Comment: OK i think here is the problem. The method glGenBuffer(1, &vertexbuffer) creates a new pointer within the video memory. The method assignes an id to vertexBuffer which identifies the buffer. You have to create for each mesh such an VertexBuffer Id, TexturbuferId. In my opinion In your code you always overload that id.

Comment: So each meshModel should have its own VertexBuffer, normalBuffer Id and so on and before calling the rendering method of each mesh you have to bind the appropriate id to the OGL State Machine

Comment: no, model is being drawed but shaders not working again. Its white and it shouldnt. I think there is a problem with shaders not the model :/

Comment: Here is the model drawing code: 
`glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 1.0f );

 shaderHelper->begin();
 model->draw();
 model->rotate( angle, glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) );

 glUniformMatrix4fv( shaderHelper->mMVPHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( camera->combined() ));
 shaderHelper->end();
 angle += 1.5f;`

Comment: I added shader loading func to the description